# How do I return a formatted string in the controller using Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I thought this would be super simple but its turning into a pain in the butt.

I need to create a function that will accept a string and return it re-formatted as a URL slug. For example I'd pass in the string "The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn" and my function would return the string "the_adventures_of_huckleberry_finn". I have no problem doing the actual conversion. However in Ember actions can only return True, False or Undefined so the action always returns an object named Undefined rather than the string I told it to return.

How can I go about creating this function/action/computed property in my controller so that it correctly returns the formatted string? I have attempted to just add a normal JS function into the controller. I also tried to define this as a computed property but this action will be used only in the controller, the template has no need to know anything about the slug so a computed property dosn't really make sense and I couldn't get it to work anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is an example in how to achieve that: jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/837

Answer (score 0):

I would return a computed property call something like slug

```
slug: function(){
 return this.get('title').split(' ').join('_');
}.property('title')
```

Then you can use `{{slug}}` in your template of this.get('slug') in your controller.

Cheers

Comment: I need to be able to pass the string into the function not hard code the title as it isn't always going to be the title, I also need to do the same thing with the author.

Comment: fanta, that worked, want to post it as an answer so I can give you the credit? Thanks mate.

Comment: I also just discovered ember has an existing string function called .underscore() which will return the string in lower case with spaces replaced with underscores. Exactlly what I needed here